# Property of Z transform

Tags: derivatives, laplace-transform, z-transform

Is there any direct relationship exist between p times differentiation of F(z) and f(n) similar to Laplace transform where n times differentiation directly related to its time domain counterpart ?

where F(z) is z-transform​ of f(n) and p is postive integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unilateral z-transform is defined by
$$
\tilde{f}(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f(n) \, z^{-n}.
$$

The derivative is
$$
\tilde{f}'(z) 
= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f(n) \, (-n) \, z^{-n-1}
= -z^{-1} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (nf(n)) \, z^{-n}
.
$$

Thus, the derivative of the z-transform is (except for the factor $-z^{-1}$) the z-transform of the sequence weighted with "position".

For higher derivatives we get
$$
\tilde{f}^{(k)}(z) 
= (-1)^k z^{-k} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n(n+1)\cdots (n+k-1))f(n)) \, z^{-n}
$$

Comment: Thanks for answer ,but what  about p times differentiation of F(z) not only only a times that I asked in question?

Comment: That will look even worse.

Comment: Added the formula for higher derivatives.